# How do I open Windows Explorer to a particular directory from a Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, command-line

When I'm in a particular directory in a Windows command prompt, I sometimes want to open Windows Explorer so it already shows that same directory.  How do I do that?

(I'm looking for the equivalent to `open .` in a Mac OS X terminal.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either one of these should do the trick:

```
explorer .
start .
```

Comment: And how do I make it point to the folder I want? It works by the so +1 ;-)

Comment: start *foldername*

Comment: If you use `start foldername` as Chris_K suggested, and only get a new `cmd.exe` window, try `start "" foldername` instead. If the first argument to `start` is quoted, it is taken not as the file/command to be started, but instead as the new window's title. So sometimes it is needed to specify an empty title to get around this idiocy.

Answer (score 2):

```
explorer.exe path
```

IE: `C:\>Explorer C:\Windows`

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
explorer %cd%
explorer %__cd__%
```