# Open the folder associated with the Command Prompt's working directory?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, cmd.exe

I am wondering if there is a command one could type into The Windows Command Prompt which would cause Windows Explorer to open a folder set at the Command Prompt's current working directory?

(This is kind of the opposite problem where people want to open the Command Prompt from the folder. I.e., opposite of this: [How can I open a command prompt in current folder with a keyboard shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/205359/how-to-open-command-prompt-in-current-folder-by-keyboard-shortcut))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening current directory in Explorer](http://superuser.com/questions/272252/opening-current-directory-in-explorer), [How do I open Windows Explorer to a particular directory from a Windows command prompt?](http://superuser.com/questions/107207/how-do-i-open-windows-explorer-to-a-particular-directory-from-a-windows-command?rq=1)

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with MS-DOS... :(

Comment: From the [tag:ms-dos] tag description: *Do not use this tag for questions about Windows command line programs or scripts.* <== please read tag descriptions before using them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
explorer %cd%
```

Should do it. %cd% will always print the current directory.

Answer (score 33):

```
explorer .
```

This is what I use.

```
start .
```

Perhaps the shortest.

Comment: I always use start . myself. fast and easy way.

Comment: I know the OP _explicitly_ asked for DOS and Windows Explorer in the post (and the tags). But for the platform-agnostic people like me who clicked because the post title was interesting, it's `xdg-open .` for most GNU/Linuxes and `open .` for OS X. The man page for `open` on Mac has lots of other useful options, too (I use `-a` all the time).

Comment: +1. the dot saves needless typing, regardless of whether you choose `explorer` or `start`.